# component is being displayed, but router-outlet is being ignored in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a router-outlet in app.component.html, admin.component.html, and manage-users.component.html. For some reason, the router-outlet in the manage-users.component.html is not outputting anything when I navigate to http://localhost:4200/admin/users

The files are structured in the following way:

```
/Admin (Module)
     admin.component.html (has router-outlet)
     admin.component.ts
     admin.module.ts
     admin-routing.module.ts
     /Manage-Users (Module within Admin module)
          manage-users.component.html (has router-outlet)
          manage-users.component.ts
          manage-users.module.ts
          manage-users-routing.module.ts
          /User-List (just a component to be displayed in manage-users outlet)
          ...
          /User-Detail (just a component to be displayed in manage-users outlet)
          ...
```

I have 3 levels of routes:

```
    // App Routes (app-routing.module.ts)
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canLoad: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: '',   redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];

    // Admin Module Routes (admin-routing.module.ts)
    const adminRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'users', component: ManageUsersComponent }
        ]
      }
    ];

    // Admin Module > Manage Users Module Routes (manage-users-routing.module.ts)
const manageUsersRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ManageUsersComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: UserListComponent},
      {path: 'edit/:id', component: UserDetailComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

**Below is what my ManageUsers.module looks like:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ManageUsersComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    UserDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ManageUsersRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService
  ]
})
export class ManageUsersModule { }
```

**Below is what my Admin.module looks like:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    ManageUsersModule
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `children` attribute inside your user routes in order to load components inside that router outlet.

The way you set up your routes is not correct You are using a routing Module for user routes however you import that module outside of UserModule what that actually does is append to the existing routes inside Admin Module.

So this is what is really happening:

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children:
        [
           { path: 'users', component: ManageUsersComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
    ...manageTenantRoutes   // your routes are being added here
];
```

One way to fix this is to use lazy loading as you did with you Admin module.

If you want to keep it this way then you have to tell exactly where these routes should be appended.

See the stackblitz for the update

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryjdxc

But you have to add it like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
import { ManageUsersComponent } from './manage-users/manage-users.component';

import { manageTenantRoutes } from './manage-users/manage-users-routing.module'
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children:
        [
          ...manageTenantRoutes
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

And change your routes to reflect this change

```
export const manageTenantRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: ManageUsersComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: UserListComponent},
      {path: 'edit/:id', component: UserDetailComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

Hope this clears it up!

Comment: Good suggestion, but still not working. Please see my update and tell me if that's what your talking about.

Comment: Where is the module for `manageUsersRoutes`? Can you show that?

Comment: I added both modules to the bottom of my post. I am aware the order I import between AdminRoutingModule and ManageUsersModule in module.ts matters, but does order matter for anything else?

Comment: I don't think you need that second children inside of your admin route. Take the users route outside of that inner children

Comment: still nothing. This is really driving me up a wall. I updated my post so you can see the change I made.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to navigate to that route? Can you add the enableTracing flag inside of your root route?

Comment: Absolutely, no error and in Augury activated_route is null.

Comment: I created a stackblitz here. Any chance you can take a look? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ki61xh You will have to manually navigate to /admin and then /admin/users or /admin/users/edit/1.

Comment: I created a stackblitz take a look while i look at yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7fx9o

Comment: Your stackblitz doesn't fully replicate mine because there is no Users.component.html in it with a router-outlet and admin.module does not import users.module. Checkout mine and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: I updated the answer with the changes and an explanation

Comment: so you got it to work without lazy loading it looks like? What was the key just removing routes from the children in the admin-routing?

Comment: you already defined user-routes like it was suppose to be lazy loaded but you didn't do it you appended everything inside Admin module. So you have to reflect that inside your user-routes as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177977/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-nico).

Comment: in the eager loading example, you say: '...manageUserRoutes // put all user routes as a children of admin so the url can be /admin/all user routes here in the admin'. What do you mean by this? If nothing is currently there when would I ever use that section? Seems like all admin/[user route] would be specified in ManageUsers-Routing.

Comment: nevermind, just realized you are using the spread operator and actually importing the routes constant from the other file, rather than importing it into the module. I was actually missing this earlier. Sorry for driving you crazy because of it.

Comment: it's okay glad you get it now! :)

Comment: I ended up just doing away with manage-tenants-routing.module and put everything in admin-routing.module. This kind of makes me feel like I am moving away from what angular recommends because they give every module its own routing file. Is the only reason I am able to import admin-routing.module into admin.module beause I am lazy loading? I am still slightly confused as to why I can import admin-routing.module into admin.module, but can't import manage-users-routing.module into manage-users.module...

Comment: Took so long, but it finally clicked. When you import a module that has a routing module imported in it's module those routes will get added at the outer level. I see now how lazy loading can get you out of this mess by just doing the lazy loading right where I want the routes to load. I also see how in some cases it doesn't matter if you import a module that has a routing module in it's module if the routes can be at the outer level. Kind of like how the Contact module is imported here: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/ngmodules/stackblitz.html

Comment: Yea that's right. That's what i was trying to explain earlier :)

Comment: I am really driving myself crazy with this. Angular docs basically say everything should be a feature module and each feature module has its own routing. With the architecture, I am trying to do is it not correct to assume Admin should be a feature module and then Users and Projects should each be feature modules within Admin. Or is this where I am going wrong and Users and Projects should simply be components within Admin and specified in admin-routing.module? I never see any examples with modules within modules. Is what I am attempting to do even a thing?

Comment: the docs will never be able to cover every scenario of everyone's projects just guidelines on how things work. You have to power to do what you want as long as you understand the benefits and limitations

Comment: alright, one final thing if you don't mind taking a look. I am creating an angular app that has a login page as the only public page. It will have two major modules since both have separate layouts: Admin and Tenant. If an admin user logs in they get directed to Admin and if a normal user logs in they get directed to their Tenant. Can you look at this stack blitz and see if you think I am breaking it out right. I am aware there is a 1000 ways to do it type of thing, would just like your opinion. App doesn't work, but focus on folder structure: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wg2u5

Comment: Can disregard my previous comment. I don't feel as bad now after reading this post since it seems like a lot of other people went crazy over this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10647 It turns out your solution with the ... is one, but an even better one is to load the actual module i.e. loadChildren: => subModuleXyz. And additionally this post https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10958